# Trying to respond to Slack depending on response other API

Tags: asynchronous, slack, node-red

I'm have difficulties of responding to Slack using Node Red. The response should wait on the response of another REST call.
I guess I need something with async await? But I can't figure out how to create the flow.
This is how the process should work

1. sent an interactive message to Slack
2. User clicks on a button (decline or Approve)
3. message is sent to Slack that request is being processed in other system
4. the request is transformed and posted to an other API /other system
5. When the response is received, then it should send the response back to Slack.

Can someone help me on this? (I'm trying to learn Node Red)

The nodejs that does exactly what I'm intent to do:

```
app.post('/review', urlencodedParser, async (req,res) => {
try{res.send(`Contract is currently being processed`)
    var request = JSON.parse(req.body.payload);
    var slackmessage = await SlackContractReviewContent(request);
    var response = await sendContractReview(slackmessage.entity, slackmessage.status);
    var Slackresponse = await sendSlackDelayedMessage(slackmessage,response);
    console.log(Slackresponse);
    res.end()
} catch (err) {
    console.log(`Could not be processed!`);
    res.end();
};
```

Comment: in general: your app needs to respond directly with HTTP 200 (step 3) and send the full response (step 5) to the `response_url` once its finished processing the other API request

Comment: of course, but I need to set a text as well "being processed" and another /2nd response when the external API has finished (HTTP 200)

Comment: the first response can include text. Just reply directly to the Slack request. Note that this will only work if the first / direct response to the Slack request includes a HTTP 200. Otherwise Slack will report a timeout error.

Comment: This can be a challenge for programming languages that only responds with HTTP 200 once the app is terminated (e.g. PHP). No idea how it works with node-red though.

Comment: thx for your comment. I've edited the message and added the nodejs sourcecode I currently use (which works as described) and I'm trying to "convert" to nodered flow.